# Put into serialized Array the value of tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent()

Tags: jquery, ajax, tinymce

How can I put in a serialized array the value that I get in tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent() so that i can pass it in another page without loading the entire page.

Here is my code:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function() {
        tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
        var f = $("#myForm");
        var action = f.attr("action");
        var serializedForm = f.serialize();
        //tinyMCE.triggerSave();
        $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: action,
             data: serializedForm,
             async: false,
             success: function(save) {
                $('#result').html(save);
                $('#result').fadeIn('slow');
             }
        });
clearInput();
return false;
});
```

In this code when I run it to the browser it redirect to the page where I save the data. I want it to stay in the current page while the data is passing to page that save the data. what I'm gonna do?

Comment: you aren't assigning the return of getContent() to any variable. Should be all you need to do

Comment: @charlietfI And after I assigned the return of the getContent() how to put it into a serialized?

Comment: I assume textarea that tinyMCE bound to is in the form, in which case  it will already be in your serializedForm variable. You should call the update method though before serializing

Comment: What is that update method? how can I can call that method? sorry but i'm not familiar in jquery or ajax i'am first timer to use this. It be better if you give me a source of what you have said.

Comment: Read the tinyMCE API Docs. There will be a method to update the form element. I don't remember exact method name so would have to do exactly what you need to do. That's how you use an API

Answer (score 0):

IF I got your question correctly, to send TinyMCE's content to another page using for instance `Ajax`, your way is a past way! You can simply send your content via `.serialize()` function without any problem. look this :

```
         $.ajax({
            type    : "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url     : "path_to_php_file_to_process",
            cache   : false,
            data    : $('#your_form_selector').serialize(),
            beforeSend: function() {//Display loading icon},
            success: function(data)
            {
                // Rest of the reponse
            }
        });
```

It was a simple `Ajax` request example and it works as well.